# Update programmatically config content text/x-magento-init script inside of phtml template

Tags: magento2, template, cache, ajax, plugin

For a requirement I had to override the config of the `configurable.js` script that is initialised inside `configurable.phtml`, this one specifically:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "configurable": {
                    "spConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>,
                    "gallerySwitchStrategy": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar('gallery_switch_strategy',
                        'Magento_ConfigurableProduct') ?: 'replace'; ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I did so with a plugin using the `afterGetJsonConfig` method and adding my data to that `spConfig` after loading the template with ajax. Everything looks good when calling the template the first time, but I need to change and keep those changes to the configuration of the component after a validation via an ajax call. The problem is that, because the template is cached, it will always return the initial content.

This is confirmed by the fact that if I disable `block_html` cache the content is updated correctly and if I turn the cache on it doesn't and it doesn't even call then `afterGetJsonConfig` method on successive page reload. Is there a way to force disable the cache or get the most updated content and retain it without being forced to disable the cache for the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `cacheable="false"` argument to the block that you have assigned the `.phtml` template in your layout .XML file

```
<block class=".." name="..." template="..." cacheable="false" />
```

This will remove the block from the caching list, basically.

More details can be found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. your code should be ok. but I want cache it and if it's updated in backend,
I want update `"spConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>`

then after visit the product page,it need cache the data again.